# dataSnapshot if else keep looping

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The below states that if the month is equal to the value in **Firebase**, it will add "monthamt" to the existing month. Else it will push a new key for the new month and store "monthamt" into it. But in my case, even thou if(a month is equal to the existing in **Firebase**, it will still push a new key with the same month).

```
 ds = mDatabase.getReference().child("Users").child(uid).child("summary");
 ds.orderByKey().addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyy");
        SimpleDateFormat fm = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");
        String month = (String) dataSnapshot.child("month").getValue();

        double mvalue = Double.valueOf(String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("monthamt").getValue()));
            mvalue = roundOff(mvalue);

        if (fm.format(c.getTime()).equals(month)) {
            String key1 = dataSnapshot.getKey();
            ds.child(key1).child("monthamt").setValue(roundOff(mvalue + amt) + "");

        }
        else if(!fm.format(c.getTime()).equals(month)) {
            String key = ds.push().getKey();
            Calendar b = Calendar.getInstance();
            ds.child(key).child("month").setValue(fm.format(b.getTime()));
            ds.child(key).child("monthamt").setValue(amt + "");
            dt.child("Bill").child(k).child("gtranid").setValue("1");
        }
    }
```

Below is what my Firebase looks like:

[image: Firebase Database]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out, code as below, instead of using else to loop, I uses if to get month which is different than those in Firebase, and add a break to every if statement to prevent looping:

```
  Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                    final int currentMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
                    ds.orderByChild("month").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener () {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                                for (DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                                    String month = data.child("month").getValue().toString();
                                    String convert1 = String.valueOf(currentMonth);

                                    if (convert1.equals(month)) {
                                        // update existing one
                                        String key = ds.getKey();
                                        double mvalue = Double.valueOf (String.valueOf(data.child("monthamt").getValue()));
                                        mvalue = roundOff(mvalue);
                                        ds.child(data.getKey()).child("monthamt").setValue(roundOff(mvalue + amt) + "");
                                        break;

                                    }
                                    if(!convert1.equals(month)){
                                    String key = ds.push().getKey();
                                    ds.child(key).child("month").setValue(convert1);
                                    ds.child(key).child("monthamt").setValue(amt + "");
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is wrong. Try something like this.

```
   String key;
   int currentMonth = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;

   ds.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener () {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            int month = data.child("month").getValue();
            if (month == currentMonth) {
               // update existing one
               key = data.getKey();
               break;
            }
          }
        }
    });

    if (key != null) {
        double mvalue = data.child("monthamt").getValue();
        mvalue = roundOff(mvalue);
        ds.child(data.getKey()).child("monthamt").setValue(roundOff(mvalue + amt) + "");
    } else {
        key = ds.push().getKey();
        ds.child(key).child("month").setValue(currentMonth);
        ds.child(key).child("monthamt").setValue(amt);
        dt.child("Bill").child(k).child("gtranid").setValue("1");
    }
```

Comment: Its not working, it pushes 2 value of the same month instead of adding it to the existing.

Comment: Now it can add value to the existing one, but still will push a new key even the month is existed already.

Comment: The if else is keep looping, even thou month existed but it will still push a new key out of nowhere. No idea why

Comment: I've fixed the issue.

Comment: I found where are the problems, system could not indicate which months to get from this code String month = String . valueOf (data.child("month").getValue());. So it will take the first one which is month "10" and push a new key whenever it is different with month "10". Please help thanks. Almost there

Comment: The idea should be if String month HAS value that is same with Calender and COMPARE it to indicate which month is same.

Comment: Yes, but it still the same.

Comment: I just could not figure out how to let system compare every month in the Firebase

Comment: We're already comparing the month here `if (month.equals(fm.format(c.getTime())))) `

Comment: But I Toast the "month" out realize it comparing month 10 only, whenever there is different month than 10, it will automatically push out a new key even thou the new month is already exist. Just because every time the system loop, it is just comparing month 10 only. It does not comparing month 11 or even 12

Comment: Yes because that what you're trying to push. when you try to push in next month, it will compare 11th month. Why do you want to compare 11th or 12th month when currently, its  10?

Comment: No, it just keep comparing 10 month. When 11 months is already exists. It will still keep pushing a new key of 11 month and not adding monthamt to the existing.

Comment: @NicholasLeong, currently, we are getting the month from `Calendar ` class which will always return the current month. that's why it's only comparing the 10th month. If you want to compare the different month, you can pass that instead of getting it from `Calendar ` class.

Comment: I test by changing the month on my android device. Calendar class should get the month from my device as well.

Comment: I tried a lot of way. It just can retrieve the first month which is 10, other than that, it just could not retrieve any other month and compare.

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a few problems with your code. Some of the first ones that jump out:

1. Why are you storing numeric values as strings? By doing so, you end up converting them repeatedly in your code, which makes that code longer and harder to maintain. I recommend storing numbers as number in the JSON.
2. If the value you want to write to the database depends on a current value in the database, you need to [use a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions).
3. If you want months to be unique in the JSON, you should use them as the key of the node, instead of as a property in there. I'd model your data as:

   ```
   "summary": {
     "month_10": 88,
     "month_11": 660
   }
   ```

   This has the advantage that you don't have to query to find the node for the month, as you already know its path:

   ```
   DatabaseReference monthRef = ds.child("month_"+mm);
   ```
4. Firebase nowadays has a built-in operation for incrementing values, so that you don't even need a transaction for this. It should be as simple as:

   ```
   monthRef.setValue(ServerValue.increment(44));
   ```

   This even works when the month node doesn't exist yet, as `increment` will simply assume that it is 0 in that case.